# Is it possible to do the improper integral or not?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I was solving the following $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t\cos^2(t)}{1+t^3} dt$. I found it exists by comparison test for integrals with $\frac{1}{t^3}$. Then, I was trying to see what happened if we changed a little bit like $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t\cos^2(t)}{1+t^2}dt$   but I was not able to do it. Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to prove it converges or trying to find the value?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio, I just changed the problem I do not know how I can do it

Comment: Your first comparison should be with something like $\frac1{t^2}$ rather than $\frac1{t^3}$

Comment: @Gob Ok, nevermind then.

Comment: @Henry, how I have $t$ in the top

Comment: $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{t\cos^2t}{1+t^2}\,dt=\infty$, because for large $t$, $\frac{t}{1+t^2}$ behaves like $\frac{1}{t}$, and because for any interval of the form $2k\pi+[\pi/4,3\pi/4]$, we have that $\cos^2t$ is bounded below by a fixed positive constant.

Comment: Did yous solve the first integral ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, yes I did

Comment: I asked because it is not so simple (even if the way to solution is simple).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I still did not get clear idea why the second one is divergent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\cos^2t={1\over 2}[\cos 2t+1]\qquad (*)$$ The integral $$\int\limits_1^\infty {t\over 1+t^2}\cos 2t \,dt$$ is convergent due to [the Dirichlet test, 17.5](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://home.iitk.ac.in/%7Epsraj/mth101/lecture_notes/lecture18.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjiisqxqf75AhUQ6CoKHWp-DG8QFnoECCwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1LguaGw28ADBfILFWomzJG). On the other hand the integral $$\int\limits_1^\infty{t\over 1+t^2}\,dt={1\over 2}\ln(1+t^2)\mid_1^\infty=\infty$$ is divergent. In view of $(*)$ the integral $$\int\limits_1^\infty {t\cos^2t\over 1+t^2}\,dt$$ is divergent.

Comment: Ryszard Szwarc, This is really great answer. Thank so much

Comment: Thanks. There are other ways but more tiring.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, thank so much. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\frac{t\cos^2(t)}{1+t^2}dt$$
$$\frac{t}{1+t^2}=\frac{t}{(t+i)(t-i)}=\frac{1}{2 (t+i)}+\frac{1}{2 (t-i)}$$ Changing variables $t=x \pm i$
$$\cos(x+i)=\frac{\left(1+e^2\right) \cos (x)}{2 e}-\frac{i \left(e^2-1\right) \sin (x)}{2 e}$$
$$\cos^2(x+i)=\frac{1}{2} (\cosh (2) \cos (2 x)\color{red}{+1})-\frac{1}{2} i \sinh (2) \sin (2 x)$$
$$\cos^2(x-i)=\frac{1}{2} (\cosh (2) \cos (2 x)\color{red}{+1})+\frac{1}{2} i \sinh (2) \sin (2 x)$$ The $\color{red}{+1}$ will lead to logarithms. Back to $t$

$$I=\frac{1}{4} \left(\cosh (2) (\text{Ci}(2 i-2 t)+\text{Ci}(2 t+2 i))+i \sinh (2)
   (\text{Si}(2 i-2 t)+\text{Si}(2 t+2 i))+\color{red}{\log \left(t^2+1\right)}\right)$$

But, moving the $\large 2$,
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{t \cos (2 t)}{1+t^2}\,dt=-\frac{e^4 (\text{Ei}(-2-2 i)+\text{Ei}(-2+2 i))+\text{Ei}(2-2 i)+\text{Ei}(2+2 i)}{4
   e^2}$$ does not make any problem.